# Django admin:custom search

Tags: django, admin

i have tow model:

```
class Site_Posts(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=300,default='')
    ...
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

class Comment(models.Model):
    post_title = models.ForeignKey(Site_Posts,null=True)
    post_id = models.IntegerField(null=True,default=None)
    ...

class Comment_Admin_Form(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Comment
    search_fields = ('content','post_title__title',)
    ...
```

i want to show all comment that `post_title` field's is equal to text of admin search box widget,but now displayed just one(Whereas there are exist many item)

Comment: The above code should work. Have you remembered to register your model admin with `admin.site.register(Comment, Comment_Admin_Form)`? What are you searching for? What result do you get if you search `Comment.objects.filter(post_title__title='<search_term>')` in the shell, and is that the same result that you get in the admin?

Comment: yes i registered model admin,my code work correctly but displayed one item insted multi item that exist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are should overwrite`get_search_results` method in your ModelAdmin class as below:

```
class X_Admin_Form(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_search_results(self, request, queryset, search_term):   # for customize search_list
        queryset,use_distinct = super(X_Admin_Form, self).get_search_results(request,queryset,search_term)
        try:
            b = Site_Posts.objects.filter(title__icontains=search_term)
            ll = []
            for item in b:
               ll.append(item.id)
            condition = Q(post_id__in=ll) | Q(another_field=search_term)
            queryset |= self.model.objects.filter(condition)

        except:
            pass

        return queryset, use_distinct
```

Answer (score 0):

The search fields should be a list, not a tuple.

```
class Comment_Admin_Form(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Comment
    search_fields = ['content','post_title__title']
```

Comment: Is no difference(list or tuple) my problem is still there